# wmaker create menus

Tags: window-maker

I generate the wmaker menu with `wmgenmenu > $HOME/GNUstep/Defaults/WMRootMenu`. It's a PropList format.

The result is better than the default menu, but not all applications show up. That is, under Gnome3 I see more of them. It's not just an issue of the same things at different places.

Where does wmgenmenu get the information about installed programs? Could it be thorough? Updating by hand won't be an option, but I'm ok updating it after installing each program.

---

Answer (score -1):

xdgmenumaker on github is the best bet to do just what you want to do. It will auto create a full menu based on .desktop files and auto update each time you open it.